# Matrix of the diagonal sobel operator of size 3x3

Tags: image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

What is the matrix of sobel operator of size 3x3 if the operator is said to be diagonal 
(Left or right  diagonal)?
EDIT: or may be with more bigger size

Comment: Should really be on mathoverflow

Comment: Not sure why this has been closed as "off-topic" as it is a computer vision related question.

Comment: May be they saw some words about matrix and decided to close this question...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 3x3 diagonal Sobel operators are:

```
[[0,1,2],
 [-1,0,1],
 [-2,-1,0]]
```

and

```
[[-2,-1,0],
 [-1,0,1],
 [0,1,2]]
```

Hope it helps.